# Wordpress: Getting URL link for archive based on custom field filter

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I am trying to provide a link on a wordpress post that will lead the user to an archive view with other posts with the same custom field.

In other words, something much like `get_author_posts_url`, but `get_customfield_posts_url`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress doesn't provide this function, you need to code this.

```
/*

    This will be your home work:

    1. You need a page with a custom template
       + query var that returns the value of the custom field
       + custom loop that (you may use meta_query) finds posts
         with the same custom field value

    2. make function to convert the custom field
       to a custom permalink may be.

    http://example.tld/my_page/?custom_field=custom_field_value
```

Comment: thanks for the respond. could you elaborate a bit more on the specifics? only a wordpress beginner.
i also read people talking about taxonomy, could that be a better choice for me?